# Variable scope in SASS mixins

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm trying to wrap my brain around this one and hopefully someone here can enlighten me. I have this code as an example:

```
@mixin stuffs() {
  color: $color;
}

$color: #000;

.single {
  $color: white;
  @include stuffs();
}
```

I would expect that $color inside the scope of .single would override the global $color value, however it does not. Can someone explain why? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - let's see if I can break this down using the example you gave.

```
@mixin stuffs() {
  color: $color;
}

$color: #000;

.single {
  $color: white;
  @include stuffs();
}
```

You're expecting that the local variable version of *$color* (i.e. white) would be displayed in the *.single* selector rather than black.

But you need to separate the local scope of *.single* from the local scope of the mixin *stuffs*. They are not the same thing. You would still need to "use" the local variable version of *$color* (i.e. white) within the *.single* selector like this:

```
@mixin stuffs() {
    color:$color;
}

$color:#000;

main
{
    $color:white;
    @include stuffs();
    color:$color;
}
```

Please let me know if I've missed something for you and check out http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498 for more information about scope.